# Getting merge commit while merging master to my own branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I am trying to merge master to my feature branch derived from master.
Master branch is already ahead by N commits.
so to merge i gave following commands after checking out my branch B1

```
1) git pull
2) git merge master
```

Both worked well, but now when i gave command:

```
git push origin B1
```

i was getting error:

> Found Merge commit in refs/heads/B1, not pushing error: failed to push
>   some refs to git@git.corp.company.com:ProjectName/bullseye.git

Any idea how to merge master to my branch remotely.

Comment: What is the output of git status on branch B1 ?

Answer (score 0):

use `git pull origin --rebase master` instead.

But use `git reflog` to see where your branch was before you did `git pull`. After you find the sha-1, `git reset sha-1 --hard` and then run the --rebase pull.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message your remote seems to dislike merges in non-`master` branches. What you should do then is rebase onto `master` instead.

```
git checkout B1
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

Usually, `rebase` should also undo all merges you already did. In case it doesn't you can undo the rebase

```
git reset --hard <sha1 of B1 before rebase>
```

and then find the commit right before the merge and reset to it:

```
git log
git reset --hard <sha1 of commit before merge>
```

afterwards you can `rebase` again. Also `git reflog` is handy to keep an overview of the different states you go through while merging and rebasing.

What you cannot do is "merge branches remotely". Git does not allow that.